# Build Error with il2cpp ARFoundation Unity 2019.2.0f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I just download arfoundation-samples, then I change scripting backend to il2cpp and get this error.

```
http://prntscr.com/op7pcu
http://prntscr.com/op7pht
http://prntscr.com/op7re9
http://prntscr.com/op7p60
```

Can I build for ARM64 with il2cpp?
My current ver unity is 2019.2.0f1. But I get this error with 2019.1.12
Please Help